# Bootstrap navbar stick to top on scroll

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, affix, scrollspy

I'm trying to have my navigation bar stick to the top of the screen on scroll. I'm using the affix plug-in to accomplish this:

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
```

Here's the relevant html.

```
 <div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Resume</h1>
 </div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="./index" title="Bio">Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="./Resume" title="My Resume">Resume</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/cody-reandeau-831038115" class="entypo-linkedin" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://github.com/codyreandeau" class="entypo-github" target="_blank" title="Github"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/codyreandeau" class="fontawesome-fire" target="_blank" title="Free Code Camp"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.hackerrank.com/codyareandeau" class="fontawesome-sitemap" target="_blank" title="Hacker Rank"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.codecademy.com/scriptSurfer86103" class="zocial-html5" target="_blank"  title="Codecademy"></a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It looks like this before the scroll:

[image]

Then when I scroll I'm off in the weeds:

[image]

I've also attempted combing it with the scrollspy and the affix plug in

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="197">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
```

And got the same results. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try changing `data-spy="scroll"` in the `nav` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a class to the navbar on scroll:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

So you just add the class `navbar-fixed-top` and it will stay right where you want it.

You can do that in jQuery very simply by running:

```
if (//scroll position reached) {
  $('nav').addClass(navbar-fixed-top)
}
```

Documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top